# Shortcuts to \section in RStudio

Tags: latex, rstudio

Is it possible to create "shortcuts" to sections, subsection etc. in the Tex part of RStudio? Similar to the R part where wrapping a "title" in ##### Title ##### creates a drop down curtain right above the console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an empty code block.  It will create the generation of the jump menu entries allowing the quick jumping and enable folding without altering output.

[image: Jump Menu]

Here's the toy contents...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\title{Sample Sweave Document}
\author{Thell Fowler}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}
<<\section*{Introduction}>>=
@
Some actual content.


\section{Concept}
<<\section{Concept}>>=
@
Some other content.


\subsection*{Algorithm}
<<\subsection*{Algorithm}>>=
@
<<HelperFunctions>>=
HelperFunction1 <- function() {
  print( "That helped!")
}
HelperFunction2 <- function() {
  print( "Oh, that helped too!")
}
@

<<MainFunction>>=
main <- function() {
  print( "I need some help!")
  HelperFunction1()
  cat( "\tbut not enough!  Let's get more help...\n")
  HelperFunction2()
  cat( "That's much better!\n")
}
@

\subsection*{Example}
<<\subsection*{Example}>>=
@

<<Example>>=
# We can get help.
main()
@

\subsubsection*{Pros}
<<\subsubsection*{Pros}>>=
@

\subsubsection*{Cons}
<<\subsubsection*{Cons}>>=
@

\end{document}
```

It may look like a pain, but it's pretty direct and simple.
<sub>Followed by VIM Mode Keys</sub>

1. Create section using the format dropdown, or just type it to keep hands on the keyboard.
2. Copy the line, or which-ever part of it you want.
   <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
3. Create/Insert the code chunk.
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
4. Paste the text between the inner <>.
   <kbd>P</kbd>
5. Delete the blank line in the function, or add echo=FALSE to the definition.
   <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no, this is not implemented in RStudio for Sweave/TeX docs.